# Apache runs in console but not as a service?

Tags: windows, apache-2.2

I have an apache 2.2 server running Django.  We have a network drive T: which we need constant access to within our Django app.  When running Apache as a service, we cannot access this drive, as far as any django code is concerned the drive does not exist.

If I add...

```
<Directory "t:/">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride None
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all
</Directory>
```

to the httpd.conf file the service no longer runs, but I can start apache as a console and it works fine, Django can find the network drive and all is well.

Why is there a difference between the console and the service?  Should there be a difference?  I have the service using my own log on so in theory it should have the same access as I do.

I'm keen to keep it running as a service as it's far less obtrusive when I'm working on the server (unless there's a way to hide the console?).  Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Is there a way to determine which user apache is running as outside of the task manager or windows services screen? I have a feeling it's running as the local system despite what windows is reporting.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're using Windows. Mapped drives are user based on Windows: they need an interactive user. It works "from the console" because you are logged in. The drive is not available to the service to when starting. I don't know if this will work, but try to change the settins of the service to run under your user. See if that helps.

You may also try to use [AutoExNT](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243486) service to run a batch file before login, something along the lines of

```
net use T: \\host\share_name /PERSISTENT:YES
```

The mapped drive may be in the context of the System account so when you login you may not be able to see the mapped drive when you login from a normal session.

I work mostly on Linux. I think some more advanced windows admins can come up with something to improve on this or give you a full recipe.

Comment: Yep, it's already logged in as me which is one of the reason's i find it so strange.